# sql checkbox and mulit select filtering

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox, filter

i'm having some problems filtering my users when a search is run.
It has to be possible to select more than one region and gender.
gender is checkboxes and region is a select multiple selector.

In my project all content is dynamic, but thats to much to show here.

the form:

```
<form action="" method="get">

    <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="1"> <!-- male -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="2"> <!-- female -->

    <select name="region[]" multiple>

        <option value="1">North</option>
        <option value="2">East</option>
        <option value="3">West</option>
        <option value="4">South</option>

    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submitSearch" value="Filter">
</form>
```

The filter function:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['submitSearch']){
        user_filter($db);
    }

    function user_filter($db){

        $gender = $_GET['gender'];
        $region = $_GET['region'];

        $sql = "SELECT name, region, img FROM users WHERE true $gender AND $region";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $res;

    }

?>
```

Not sure if i have do a loop with the arrays and there is a problem with WHERE true if nothing is set

hope somebody can help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
if(isset($_GET['submitSearch']){
    user_filter($db);
}

function user_filter($db){

    $gender = implode(",",$_GET['gender']); //Change array to comma separated string so easy to pass in mysql using IN keyword
    $region = implode(",",$_GET['region']);

    $sql = "SELECT name, region, img FROM users WHERE gender IN($gender) AND region IN ($region)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $res;

}
```

**Updated code for conditions**

```
function user_filter($db){

        if(isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] !=''){
            $gender = implode(",",$_GET['gender']); //Change array to comma separated string so easy to pass in mysql using IN keyword
        }
        if(isset($_GET['region']) && $_GET['region'] !=''){
            $region = implode(",",$_GET['region']);
        }


        $genderSql = "";
        $regionSql = "";
        $where = "";

        $sql = '';
        $sql .="SELECT name, region, img FROM users";

        if(isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] !=''){
            $genderSql =" gender IN($gender)"; //Note Space at start 
        }

        if(isset($_GET['region']) && $_GET['region'] !=''){
            if(isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] !=''){
                $regionSql =" AND region IN ($region)"; //Note Space at start 
            } else {
                $regionSql =" region IN ($region)"; //Note Space at start 
            }
        }


        if((isset($_GET['gender']) && $_GET['gender'] !='') || (isset($_GET['region']) && $_GET['region'] !='')){
            $where =" Where";
            $sql .=$where.$genderSql.$regionSql;
        }


        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $res;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem now if nothing is set, see I forgot to tell that that i'm showing all users before a search is done

Comment: First let me clear two things (1)If no Gender and Religion is selected then so all records (2)Both will be selected together or can be selected separately.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. yes, frist i'm showing all records(users), if only gender is clicked then show users where gender is male or female or both. if region is also set the show region/regions and gender is that is set. Makes sense? thanks, already been helping me a lot :)

Comment: @user3426191 See my updated answer. Please check this with every possible condition and if you have any concern then let me know

Comment: thanks a lot, it did the job, and was by far more complicated than i thought it would be